# Can we use collection variable as a table in execute immediate?

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, collections, execute-immediate

```
Declare

Type t_approved_node is record( node_rowid Hr 
node_rowid%type, Node_+type hr.node_type%type);

Type t_val is table of t_approved_node Index by pls_integer;

V_node t_val;

V_tab varchar2(20);
V_col varchar2(400);
V_nrf_flg hr.hr_flag%type;
V_ubrf_flg hr.hr_flag%type := 3;
V_col_str varchar2(4000);

Begin

Begin
Select hr_flag into v_nrf_flg from hr;
End;

Begin
Select h.node_rowid, h.node_type bulk collect into v_node 
 from hr h,  hr_attr_wfm  haw
 Where h.hr_relation_id = haw.uc_hr_relation_id
 And h.node_type = 'UBR';

Begin
V_tab := 'UC_UBR';
Select listagg(column_name, ',' within group(order by 
column_id)
Into v_col from user_tab_columns where table_name = v_tab;
End;

 V_col_str := regex_replace( v_col, 'HR_FLAG', v_ubrf_flg);
 Execute immediate ' insert into ' || v_tab || '( ' ||
                                  V_col || ') ' || ' select '|| v_col_str || ' from ' ||
                                  V_tab || 'R ' || q' [ where node_type = ' UBR' a 
and hr_flag =:1 and  exists( ] ' || ' select 1 ' || ' from table( ' || 
v_node ||  ')y' || q' [ where y.node_rowid = R.node_rowid ] )'
Using v_nrf_flag;

End;

End;
```

I was trying to execute above block getting below error.

> Wrong number or types of arguments in call to ||

Final query should be like

```
insert into UC_UBR ( v_col)/*3 columns into v_col variable*/
select v_col_str /* 3 columns in v_col_str variable*/ from UC_UBR R where  hr_flag =:1
and    exists
       (select 1 from table(v_node) /*collection variable*/ y
        where y.node_rowid = r.node_rowod;
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Concatenation is an operation on strings. You cannot pass everything into string and expect that DBMS will guess what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code is full of errors and does not make any sense at all. But if I focus on your question, then the answer is "yes". See this example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_app AS OBJECT( nodeid NUMBER, Nodetype VARCHAR2(100));
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_val IS TABLE OF t_app;

DECLARE
    
    V_node t_val;
    V_result t_val;
    V_app t_app;
    V_count NUMBER;
    Sql_stmt VARCHAR2(100);
    
    nodeid NUMBER; 
    Nodetype VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

    SELECT t_app(nodeid, Nodetype) BULK COLLECT INTO V_node FROM HR;
    
    Sql_stmt := 'SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE(:t)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Sql_stmt INTO V_count USING V_node;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'V_count = ' || V_count );

    Sql_stmt := 'SELECT nodeid, Nodetype FROM TABLE(:t) WHERE ROWNUM = 1';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Sql_stmt INTO nodeid, Nodetype USING V_node;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'nodeid = ' || nodeid  );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Nodetype = ' || Nodetype  );

    Sql_stmt := 'SELECT t_app(nodeid, Nodetype) FROM TABLE(:t) WHERE ROWNUM = 1';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Sql_stmt INTO V_app USING V_node;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'V_app =  ' || XMLTYPE(V_app).getClobVal()  );

    Sql_stmt := 'SELECT t_app(nodeid, Nodetype) FROM TABLE(:t)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Sql_stmt BULK COLLECT INTO V_result USING V_node;

END;
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code in possible way. Could you please check now and Thank you very much for your time .I am new to plsql Coding. Your answer will help me.

Comment: Stick to my code. For an INSERT statement just skip the `BULK COLLECT INTO ...` / `INTO ...`. Run `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` for the generated SQL statement in order to verify it as @Littlefood did it.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted real code you used, because this is full of syntax errors (missing `sql_stmt` local variable declaration, `put.line` (?)).

I have no idea what you plan to do with such a `select` statement as you can't execute it, it doesn't make any sense but - here you go; see line **#20**.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE t_app IS RECORD
  3     (
  4        nodeid     NUMBER,
  5        Nodetype   VARCHAR2 (20)
  6     );
  7
  8     TYPE t_val IS TABLE OF t_app
  9        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
 10
 11     V_node    t_val;
 12     V_tab     VARCHAR2 (20);
 13
 14     sql_stmt  VARCHAR2 (200);
 15  BEGIN
 16     SELECT empno, ename
 17       BULK COLLECT INTO v_node
 18       FROM emp;
 19
 20     Sql_stmt := 'select 1 from (' || v_node (1).nodeid || 'Y)';
 21
 22     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (sql_stmt);
 23  END;
 24  /
select 1 from (7369Y)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code in possible way. Could you please check now and Thank you very much for your time .I am new to plsql Coding. Your answer will help me.